# Azure Event Hubs Changing Partition Key

Tags: azure, partitioning, azure-eventhub

An application sets the value of `EventData.PartitionKey` to a new `Guid` upon start-up. For each new deployment, the Partition Key will therefore change.

I understand that Event Hubs leverage a hashing mechanism in order to route messages to specific Partitions. Does regenerating the Partition Key impede, or affect, this mechanism in any detrimental way?

I notice from time to time that messages do not appear in the Event Hub (regardless of how much time has passed) after multiple deployments, despite the fact that the underlying `EventHubClient.SendBatchAsync` method does not throw an `Exception`. The behaviour appears to correct itself arbitrarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The impact would be: each time your App restarts - the messages could land in an entirely different Partition - because, the new Guid could be hashed to a different EventHub Partition.

This wouldn't hurt EventHub performance in any way. You can generate as many PartitionKey's as you need.

But, the Application consuming these events would be impacted: typically there would be one Worker processing the events out of a Single-Partition (**EventHubs partitions are the Unit-of-Scale for the event-processers processing events out of EventHubs**). When your App started with Guid1 - it might be hashed to Partition1 which is being processed by ProcessorInstance1, but, when the App restarts - it would generate Guid2 which might be hashed to Partition10 which is being processed by ProcessorInstance10. The principle behind any Application using `PartitionKey` is **Correlation** - all `EventData`'s using the same `PartitionKey` would land on Same EventHub partition. But, this key is being reset - which defeats the whole purpose.

All `SendBatch` Operations will throw if the operation doesn't succeed. This is the fundamental guarantee & an impossible SLA breach - if it doesn't throw. I believe, from the symptoms you explained, after an App deployment, since the new Guid will result into events landing on different partitions - you might be receiving events out of a specific partition & could be missing to see them & it could auto-correct if you generate another Guid which maps to old Partition... I would strongly recommend to fix the Map of `partitionKey` to a `random`Guid.

[more on Event Hubs...](https://link.medium.com/ZFqhxR8myW)

Comment: Am I correct in saying that regardless of the amount of time that both `Stream` and `Event Hubs` have been running, any given static value, such as an IP address, will always map to the same partition based on the underlying hashing mechanism?

Comment: Is it possible that the `Event Hub` `Throughput-Unit` count must equal the `Stream Analytics` `Streaming Unit` count, in order to correctly synchronize? The only instance in which I can conclude message-loss, is if `Stream Analytics` explicitly connects to specific `Event Hub` `Partitions`.

Comment: I am not a `Stream Analytics` expert.. but, from the description - investigate in that direction - to configure `Stream Analytics` to pull from all `Partition`s ?.