# Azure Stream Analytics Event Hub No Events

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

An `Azure Stream Analytics` job exports events to an `Azure Event Hub`, based on this `Query`:

```
SELECT ipAddress, httpRequestTime
INTO Outlet
FROM Inlet
TIMESTAMP BY HttpRequestTime
```

No events are output to the `Event Hub`. However, if I change the `Query`, removing the `TIMESTAMP` clause, all events are output:

```
SELECT ipAddress, httpRequestTime
INTO Outlet
FROM Inlet
```

Why does the `TIMESTAMP` clause perclude the events from reaching the `Event Hub`?

Incidentally, if the point of this `Query` is unclear, the original `Query` was more complex, and by process-of-elimination, I have isolated to problem to the `TIMESTAMP` clause.

Comment: Try changing the casing of HttpRequestTime to httpRequestTime in your TIMESTAMP BY statement so it matches your SELECT statement.  This shouldn't matter as it should be case insensitive but worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, but I had already tried that without success

Comment: Incidentally, httpRequestTime is an ISO 8601 compliant string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Partition Key` changed multiple times during development, which seems to have disrupted the mapping between `Stream Analytics` job and downstream `Event Hub` `Partitions`, resulting in message-loss.

Deleting and re-creating both up and downstream `Event Hubs`, and resetting the associated `Stream Analytics` input and outputs, re-calibrated the `Partition-mappings` and resolved the issue.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999025/azure-event-hubs-changing-partition-key) outlines the underlying cause in detail.